# How to implement paypal payment integration in iphone?

Tags: iphone, paypal

I have created one application in iphone sdk.
i have already taken user credit card details like ccnumber,ccverification number etc..
now i have task to implement pay button on this user clicks the button payment should be done.
user must not have to enter its credit-card no or other details because as i have taken already.so user interaction should not be done.

I have used this method

```
-(IBAction)pay:(id)sender
  {
   //       perfomingSetMobileCheckout=YES;
  //        recordResults = FALSE;

    NSString *parameterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"USER=myuser"
                                 "&PWD=mypassword"
                                 "&SIGNATURE=mysignature"
                                 "&METHOD=DoDirectPayment"
                                 "&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa"
                                 "&ACCT=1234"
                                 "&EXPDATE=sep/11"
                                 "&CVV2=256"
                                 "&AMT=6549"
                                 "&FIRSTNAME=Demo"
                                 "&LASTNAME=Test"
                                 "&STREET=WallStreet"
                                 "&CITY=HI"
                                 "&STATE=Ohio"
                                 "&COUNTRY=US"
                                 "&ZIP=98251"
                                 "&COUNTRYCODE=US"
                                 "&PAYMENTACTION=Sale"
                                 "&VERSION=2.3"];
                                // txtCreditCardType.text,txtAccountNumber.text,txtExpireDate.text,txtTotalAmount.text,txtFirstName.text,txtLastName.text,txtStreet.text,txtCity.text,txtState.text,txtCountry.text,txtZip.text];

    NSLog(@"parameter:%@",parameterString);

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?%@",parameterString];
    NSLog(@"str:=%@",str);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp"];

                            //https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
                            //https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp;
    NSLog(@"url:%@",url);
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [parameterString length]]; 
    NSLog(@"msgLength:%@",msgLength);
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"theRequest:%@",theRequest);



    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Connection:%@",theConnection);
    if( theConnection )
    {
        NSMutableData *webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"Data:=%@",webData);
        //[self displayConnectingView];

    }else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}
```

So when user tap the pay button payment should be done by paypal & user only get the message that payment done or not.

how to implement that payment button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the PayPal payment library for iOS.  It does everything for you!

[PayPal library](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep)

Comment: But I have to post direct data to paypal for the payment process this library is opening paypal payment panel.At their i have to push on the paybutton. i dont want to show this screen.

Comment: @Hrushikesh i need to implement Simple Payment Using PayPal. Like one person want to donate x dollors to charity. When i have give the mearchant id with me. How can i imp[lent this. I tried with Paypal Library above in the link. When run sample application given by sdk it works fine. But when i am trying to in my application  it wont works it will getting crash. Please suggest me in this issue